# Latitude and longitude columns in QGIS not autopopulating

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

So I created columns for latitude and longitude for a point layer in QGIS using the expressions $y and $x in the field calculator respectively. However whenever I add a new point feature the latitude and longitude have null values. Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a default value for your Latitude and Longitude fields under the Attributes Form tab of the Layer Properties dialog.

Use `$y` and `$x` as default values and check Apply default value on update:

[image]

Now the values in the Latitude and Longitude fields will auto populate and update when you add or move a point feature.

Answer (score 1):

They fields are not continuously updated as dynamic attributes. You will need to run the calculation again to get an update, including for new features.

Comment: So I will have to the field of calculator each time to update all of the new rows with NULL values?

Comment: Yes, but it should be noted that given you can calculate these as simple $x and $y expressions from the geometry, why are you writing these into columns at all when you already have the geometry?